# backbone view test if element has datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, bootstrap-datepicker

First off: sorry for the terrible topic name

I have a backbone view that has an onRender() method.
What it does is initializing all selects with an select jquery plugin (chosen) and some input text fields with the jquery plugin bootstrap-datepicker (https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker).

here is the code (coffeescript)

```
  onRender: =>
    ### init chosen select picker ###
    $('.chosen-select', @el).chosen
      width: '100%'
    ### init datepickers ###
    $('.date', @el).datepicker()
```

Now I want to write specs for the view and I am stuck with testing if the datpickers and chosen-selects where initialized on the proper elements elements.

So I strart trying on the console:

it was easy for the chosen-selects:

```
/* lets build the view  */
v = new MyBackboneView();
v.render();
v.onRender();
/* now lets grab a select that I expect to be an chosen select now */
select = $(':input[name="user_id"]', v.el);
/* now I check for the chosen function on the element */
$(select).data('chosen'); /* => is not undefined, yay! */
```

So now I wanted to do the same for the datepicker stuff.

```
/* lets build the view  */
v = new MyBackboneView();
v.render();
v.onRender();
/* now lets grab a input text field that I expect to be a datepicker now */
input = $(':input[name="start_date"]', v.el);
/* now I check for the datepicker function on the element */
$(input).data('datepicker'); /* => is undefined :-( */
```

So I can't check for the datepicker this way. But here is what I don't understand.

If I load the page in the browser, and I do the same thing like above with the element rendered in the browser (not only oon the console) I see the wanted object when checking for

```
$(input).data('datepicker');
```

So basicly when view is shown in browser:

```
/* lets grab a input text field that I expect to be a datepicker now */
input = $(':input[name="start_date"]');
/* now I check for the datepicker function on the element */
$(input).data('datepicker'); /* => is defined :-O */
```

Can someone explain this to me? I can't see through this one.
And furthermore. Is there a better way to check for the use of a datepicker on an element in the console (or in an unit test)?

Comment: (1) You should probably say `@$('.chosen-select')` instead of  `$('.chosen-select', @el)` and `input = v.$(':input[name="start_date"]')` instead of `input = $(':input[name="start_date"]', v.el)` if you're using Backbone. (2) Can you replicate this problem without Backbone (i.e. with just plain jQuery and Bootstrap)? (3) Where does your view's `el` come from? Is it an existing element? Does the view create it? Who puts it on the page?

Comment: I don't understand point 3.
The views el comes from the view. Its a form tag. It's filled in the views redner method. all working fine. When logging the views el I see my template.
Its not in the page. It just lives in the console. I do so because I want to write a test (mocha) that checks if the onRender method does its job.

about point 2: mh, seems to wok if I just do it with jquery on the console. I need to take a further look in the backbone docs

Comment: Does the view create the `el` or is the view trying to attach itself to a `<form>` that is already on the page? That's what (3) is asking. Does the datepicker assume that the things it is binding to will be on the page somewhere? This is sort of what (2) is about. Building a minimal stripped down example using just jQuery and Bootstrap would help.

Comment: What _mu_ is asking is a [mcve].